# How can the authentication be implemented for RESTful web applications?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, web-applications, authorization

I'm writing a web application in JavaScript (client) and Python/Google App Engine (service) where I want users to add their data. I created a welcome page which will have the sign-in/sign-up box. After entering the correct username/password I want the user to be authorized and then forwarded to the web app page and make the user send AJAX requests to a RESTful service with the specified user's id, i.e. (host/{userid}/some_resource) - and on the service side make sure the user is authorized.

How can I achieve that and make everything safe (i.e. never send username/password in cleartext)? I found some "buzzwords" like "HTTP authentication" and "sessions", but was unable to find a reliable and clear article on how to implement those kind of things.

I also wonder how different popular sites handle the authorization (i.e. GMail works over HTTPS; Stackoverflow and Facebook seem to use HTTP).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a fan of re-inventing the wheel, so I'd recommend you either go with the built-in Google Accounts (or OpenID) integration that GAE has or go with Django user authentication.

Google Accounts/OpenID on GAE python: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/

Django authentication: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

This way you have everything you need to manage users and with Django, you also get permissions framework.

Comment: I would go for Google Accounts/OpenID, but I need the users to have unique display names. Can I do that with Google Accounts/OpenID?

Comment: There is a unique identifier assigned to the user. Under federated authentication (OpenID), google will treat the user as any other user you get through the Users API. Here are the full docs: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/openid.html. Please note that this feature is still experimental.

Comment: @Stefan Just ask users to pick a display name after they log in for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want is a session. When the user logs in the server gives them back a unique token that specifies a session or user in the system. Whenever the user makes a subsequent request they pass back the token so the server can check it and make sure the user is allowed to do whatever they are trying to do.

In a web app you usually create a session on the server side and pass back the token as a cookie. The users browser will automatically send this token to the server on each request so the server can see that the user is authenticated. This is what Gmail, Stack Overflow, and Facebook (and nearly every website) does.

If you want to use cookies for this on GAE you can use the built in Google user system and it will automatically create the session and cookie and all you have to do is use the users API to figure out who is logged in (see users example in GAE docs). If you would rather not use the Google user system (because you don't want to require your users to have a Google account) you can roll your own session system or use an established library such as GAE-Sessions (https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions). There is some example code on that site on how to use it.

Aside: RESTful APIs that are not strictly used by web browsers often do not use cookies for authentication. They either create a token for each user up front (when the user is created) or when the user logs in (pass the token back in the response to the login request) and the user passes that token back to the server in their requests as either a parameter or as a HTTP header.

In both of the above cases you could have the login happen over HTTPS and the rest of the actions over HTTP and it would work without any extra effort on your part however the token being passed to the server from the client would be sent insecurely over HTTP which is bad. Lots of session systems will keep track of which IP address a session belongs to so if someone tries to hijack a session by copying their token they cannot get in but, unless you have a good reason not to, you should just use HTTPS for everything.